# Exception with syncing SQL Server CE and Azure

Tags: sql, synchronization, sql-server-ce, azure-sql-database

So during the `orch.Synchronize()`, `orch` being my `SyncOrchestrator` I get the a `InvalidOperationException`, that says

> The stored procedure '[Sync_Matter_bulkinsert]' doesn't exist.

I tried doing research on the matter but nothing has helped.

In fact I couldn't even find anything to do with `Sync_Matter_bulkinsert`, so I am kind of stumped. Any information would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're using Sync Framework? Did you carry out provisioning on each database? Provisioning creates all the necessary stored procedures and triggers that the framework uses.

Comment: Yes I carried out the provisioning, for some reason i am actually getting an exception for the provisioning now too which may be related. It is giving me a DbPartiallyProvisionedException with a message: "Invalid column name 'ISQLHELPERCACHEDPRIMARYCLIENTNAME'."
This happens when i try to apply provisioning to the azure database @MattSull